# Spring Data Neo4j repository has PagingAndSortingRepository absent

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have implemented a small use case to evaluate Spring Data Neo4j. I have a `PublicRepository` interface which extends `GraphRepository`.

The interface looks like this:

```
public interface PublicRepository extends GraphRepository<Tweet> {}
```

This is giving me Error `"The hierarchy of the type PublicRepository is inconsistent"`.

> This type of error comes because One of the Class/interface,
>   extended/implemented by current class,  which in turn is
>   extending/implementing another class/interface is absent.

After looking into the core library's package `org.springframework.data.repository` I found that the interface `PagingAndSortingRepository`, extended by `CRUDRepository` is absent in the library. I searched for the same into the Github Repository of the [Neo4j Data](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/tree/GA). But this interface is absent over there as well.

I searched over google for the same but not found solution to this issue and not even into issue queue of Neo4j Data. Hence have filed one, refer [this](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/issues/92).

- Has anyone came across this issue?
- Is there any other way to integrate Neo4j Data Library with spring application?
- Where can I find the spring-data-neo4j jar file with this interface?
- If not, where can I find the interface definition file which I can integrate with the currently compiled jars? What are the environment settings required for the same?

Comment: Got Solution!...Was missing commons library in jars causing the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was solved here in [github issues](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/issues/92#issuecomment-11123411)